# Python - how to control another program?

Tags: python

How to control another program, written in a different language?
For example, using OllyDbg know that clicking on the button invokes a particular function - using my program written in Python wants to call this function.

Comment: The "other program" matters.

Comment: pywinauto can do it on windows, or pysendkeys. ... or autoit , but that has its own scripting language ... there are several other simillar ones

Comment: pywinauto - too simple. I need control e.x game

Comment: Patching a game binary on-the-fly, uh? This involves heavy wizardry. If you have to ask, probably these spells are away above your level.

Comment: Try to describe how you'd expect this thing to actually work.